# jQuery Mobile custom link CSS style

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, hyperlink

I'm having an issue getting custom link styles to work when dropped in the jQuery Mobile CSS file that I downloaded.

Here is an example of two types of code I'm using:

```
.body A:link {color: #5f8bff; text-decoration: none}
.body A:visited {color: #5f8bff; text-decoration: none}
.body A:active {color: #5f8bff; text-decoration: none}
.body A:hover {color: #5f8bff ; text-decoration: underline; color: #ffffff;}

.body2 A:link {color: #e1d34b; text-decoration: none}
.body2 A:visited {color: #e1d34b; text-decoration: none}
.body2 A:active {color: #e1d34b; text-decoration: underline}
.body2 A:hover {color: #5f8bff; text-decoration: underline; color: #ffffff;}
```

This code isn't responding when placed in a `<span class="body">` and `<span class="body2">`.

The example URL is here: www.camavision.com/wp/jquery

Any suggestions?  I'm trying to create three different types of link styles to override the current CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as long as your custom CSS is loaded last, and your CSS is specific enough, then it should be overriding anything before it.

Make sure you are referencing the right stuff by putting a "!important" next to it.  for example

```
.body2 A:link {color: #e1d34b !important; text-decoration: none}
```

If that works, then you are pointing at the right place but aren't being specific enough or loading it in incorrect order.

NOTE: Don't actually use the !important unless absolutely necessary, just use it to further troubleshoot

EDIT:

try adding .ui-link to your a tag

```
    .body2 a.ui-link {color: #e1d34b; text-decoration: none}
```

to all your statements

Comment: You may ask the user to refer to specificity documentation than putting !important which over-rides even inline css or css applied by the script. Here's the Link for refernce to specificity documentation.
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: I did put a special not saying not to use it, and to use it for testing purposes. where you not able to read the second half of post?

Comment: I moved the custom CSS to the bottom of the CSS file (I had it incorrectly placed at the beginning). However, using any of the specific tags (body, body2, body3) still doesn't produce any successful results. Would placing these style tags within the "index.html" file before the close of the </head> work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/snBuv/

I'm using the default jQuery Mobile 1.3.2 CSS file found here and attempting to drop that CSS style coding inside: http://jquerymobile.com/download/

Comment: Any suggestions on CSS overwrites would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/snBuv/1/

seems to work for me, switch the body number around

Comment: Thanks for testing. That code is indeed working. However, when applied within the jQuery CSS file it doesn't seem to take. Not sure why. Still continuing to test.

Comment: can you make a jsfidle that replicates your exact problem? put in the html that is being used ect

Comment: All CSS dropped in with the link style code at the bottom. It's working when testing within this framework. However, when applied to the actual mobile website it doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/KRp5C/

Comment: can you link me to the mobile site where it isn't working? are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Mobile site: http://www.camavision.com/wp/jquery/

Choose the "A" list and you can see the three test links displayed. They all default to the blue link within the jQuery Mobile CSS instead of taking on the span class they were identified with.

Comment: UPDATE: Using the !important tag has created an option for the colors to show! I avoided using it based on prior feedback, but that did the trick!